# JAXB namespace switching

Tags: java, xml, jpa, jaxb

I have a requirment where I had created XSD's based on my JPA domain classes (in this domain classes some generic classes are there like some common classes Address, Name, Phone etc ..).

I had created two XSD's with two namespaces. one which is common across all JPA domain classes (like Address, Phone, Name etc..) and another with root XSD's which includes all JPA domain classes.

on abstract I have one to one mapping between the JAXB package with JPA domain package classes. Is there any option available to expose my JPA domain classes into JAXB objects with no namespace conflicts from the client who is going to receive my XML ?

If yes can i have the sample code ?

Comment: Here is an article that will help with JAXB and namespaces:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html